# JSONException: No value for courseDivide

Tags: java, android-studio

Just tried to run and I receive this error:

> JSONException: No value for courseDivide
>   StatisticsFragment$ByEntire.onPostExecute(StatisticsFragment.java:225)
>   StatisticsFragment$ByEntire.onPostExecute(StatisticsFragment.java:153)

I'm a beginner with Java and I can't seem to figure out why JSONException has No value.

The code:

```
class ByEntire extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String target;
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());  

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

        try{
            target = "http://wook1150.cafe24.com/ByEntire.php";
            dialog.setMessage("로딩중");   
            dialog.show();                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(target);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String temp;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(temp + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public  void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){
        super.onProgressUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public  void onPostExecute(String result){
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
            int count = 0;
            int courseID;
            String courseGrade;
            String courseTitle;
            String courseProfessor;
            int courseCredit;
            int courseDivide;     //////Error here//////
            int coursePersonnel;
            String courseTime;

            while(count < jsonArray.length()){

                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                courseID = object.getInt("courseID");
                courseGrade = object.getString("courseGrade");
                courseTitle = object.getString("courseTitle");
                courseProfessor = object.getString("courseProfessor");
                courseCredit = object.getInt("courseCredit");
                courseDivide = object.getInt("courseDivide)");
                coursePersonnel = object.getInt("coursePersonnel)");
                courseTime = object.getString("courseTime)");
                rankList.add(new Course(courseID, courseGrade, courseTitle, courseCredit, courseDivide, coursePersonnel,courseTime, courseProfessor));
                count++;
                dialog.dismiss();   
            }
            rankListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Because your JSON object has no value for the `courseDivide` key?

Comment: It happens because your document doesn't have `courseDivide` value.

Comment: Your JSON doesnt have `courseDivide` and is it mistyping `courseDivide = object.getInt("courseDivide)");` ?

Comment: I found the mistyping and finally I made it. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be your JSON doesnt have courseDivide or mistyping, remove the ')'

```
courseDivide = object.getInt("courseDivide");
coursePersonnel = object.getInt("coursePersonnel");
courseTime = object.getString("courseTime");
```